# Странная нагрузка на сайт

Tags: веб-программирование, apache

Мой сайт вторую неделю подвергается то ли атаке, то ли неправильным запросам из-за кривых рук.

В Apache была ошибочна включена опция `ProxyRequests On`, глобально. Ошибка была обнаружена при поиске причин тормозов сервера. Во вторник опция была отключена, но запросы все равно идут. Большинство запросов типа: `ib.adnxs.com` `GET http://ib.adnxs.com/ttj?id=5077287&cb=${CACHEBUSTER} HTTP/1.0" 404 157` . Естественно, домен ib.adnxs.com не соответствует моему.

Это атака или кривые руки? Как это остановить? Запросы приходят с разных ip.

Apache работал с дикими тормозами. Почему столь популярный сервер такой тормоз? Пришлось развернуть собственный сервер. Сейчас, судя по логу, на сервер идут 50 запросов в секунду. Апач, когда вис, показывал в логах порядка 10.

Comment: apache уже далеко не первый год вытесняется nginx, в котором как минимум есть большинство функционала апача, причем в более эффективной реализации. Просто выбор за счет популярности поддерживает эту самую популярность, в то время как nginx практически веб-сервер по умолчанию в любом крупном проекте.

Comment: *Просто выбор за счет популярности поддерживает эту самую популярность* — мне кажется, к *nginx-у* это применимо в неменьшей степени.

Answer (score 3):

> Как это остановить?

я бы воспользовался таким алгоритмом:

1. остановить *apache*
2. установить и настроить под свои нужды *fail2ban*
3. включить *apache*